# React - Prevent scrolling to top after changing query params

Tags: reactjs, react-router, gatsby

In my Gatsby app I have a page that includes a pagination component.

By default, the path is: **'/?page=1'** and clicking the pagination buttons changes to **'/?page=2'**,  **'/?page=3'** ...

I am "saving" the page number in the path because I want the browser to remember the page number the user was on previously, in case he clicks the ***go back button*** of the browser.

The problem with this approach is that every time the path is changed, the page automatically is scrolling to the top, and I do not want it to scroll to the top.

Does anyone know the way to prevent that?

Answer (score 1):

This is the default Gatsby behavior (known as [Scroll Restoration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/routing/scroll-restoration/)). You have exposed the `useScrollRestoration` hook in order to play with this behavior (and change it accordingly to your specifications). For example:

```
import { useScrollRestoration } from "gatsby"
import countryList from "../utils/country-list"
export default function PageComponent() {
  const ulScrollRestoration = useScrollRestoration(`page-component-ul-list`)
  return (
    <ul style={{ height: 200, overflow: `auto` }} {...ulScrollRestoration}>
      {countryList.map(country => (
        <li>{country}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

In your case, you should add your element class name.

Related GitHub threads:

- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/27349
- https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/19480